# If condition than validate in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have been struggling with a problem for a while and I have not found any answers on the Internet!
Is it possible in R Shiny in server.R file to have soothing like this:

```
if(condition) validate(need(a==b), "message")
```

It gives me error! Thank you!

Comment: Ideally should look like this:                                                                                                                     'if(input$nvaccinated==input$ncows) {
validate(need(input$ninfectedinit==input$initvaccination),"Please correct!"))
    }' But it gives this error when I actually put the case nvaccinated=ncows and the ninfectedinit != initvaccination it doesn't say "please correct!" but it shows error message: argument "label" is missing, with no default

Comment: All done, just a missplaced ")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spot the ")" in the end not after a==b
if(condition) validate(need(a==b, "message"))